# Writing multiple image files In specific folder

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, writefile

I have a images which i have read in specific format later on i have to find contours and write all contour images in to specified the output folder. And then i have to create sub folder under the name of filename and write the segmented images to the relevant folders. Till now i am able to read images in specified format whereas i am able to find contours but not able to write all those contour images in specific folder.

```
import cv2
import os, os.path

print (cv2.__version__)

imageDir = "C:/Users/animesh.singh/Downloads/Assignment/" #specify your path here

image_path_list = []

valid_image_extensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".tif", ".tiff"] 

#specify your valid extensions here
valid_image_extensions = [item.lower() for item in valid_image_extensions]

for file in os.listdir(imageDir):

extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]

    if extension.lower() not in valid_image_extensions:
        continue
    image_path_list.append(os.path.join(imageDir, file))

for imagePath in image_path_list:

    img = cv2.imread(imagePath)

    if img is None:
        continue

    cv2.imshow(imagePath, img)

    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if key == 27: # escape
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()


for imagePath in image_path_list:

    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    edges = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 200)

    cv2.imshow(imagePath,thresh)
    cv2.imshow(imagePath,edges)

    key = cv2.waitKey(0)

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for contour in contours:

      cv2.drawContours(img, [contour], 0, (0, 0, 255), 3)

cv2.imwrite('C:/Users/animesh.singh/Downloads/Assignment/contour_images/1 (103)_N_0_0_CARD_Contour_Output.jpg', img)
```

I want:

• Read all the images from folder, which accept all image formats other than PDF.

• Find contours and write all contour images in to specified the output folder.

• Create sub folder under the name of filename and write the segmented images to the relevant folders.

Input images:

1:

[image: Image_1]

2:

[image: Image_2]

3:

[image: Image_3]

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be attempting to write the segmented images at all. What problem are you running into?

Comment: @JosepValls well till now i am stuck in step two where i need to write contour images of all 3 input images but i am able to write just 1

Comment: I think you've either messed up the indentation in your code here, or the indentation in your original code, starting with the "contours, hierarchy =..." line. Indent basically everything from that line down one tab to the right.

Comment: @user3757614 If you know the problem kindly help because i cant understand what you are saying.

Comment: Do you want to store each character as a separate image?

Comment: @J.D. Yes as a separate image and in separate folder containing name of folder as file name.

Comment: @JosepValls any update sir regarding the problem...

Comment: @J.D. I am having trouble while executing this on all 3 images in image path list is it possible for you to write code for same i will be highly thankful to you

Comment: @J.D. 
  File "<ipython-input-75-704d1994e468>", line 4, in <module>
    path = "C:/Users/animesh.singh/Desktop//"+filename

**TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str  **                                                                                                                                for imagePath in image_path_list:
    filename = image_path_list
    # create a folder for this image
    path = "C:/Users/animesh.singh/Desktop//"+filename
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

Comment: @J.D. 
  File "<ipython-input-48-c70ee3ac2377>", line 3, in <module>
    path = basepath+filename[:filename.index(".")]

ValueError: substring not found

Comment: @J.D. still having problem now the segmented images of first image is being written in folder 2nd and 3rd images folder is being created but the folder is empty...

Comment: Seems to be an issue local to you, because all images work for me. If a folder is created that means that the script found the file and it has a valid extension. Add `print(filename)`, `print(img.shape)` and `print(len(contours))` right above `for i in range(len(contours)):` to check if the images are loaded and/or contours are found

Comment: @J.D. Only one file is being read.print(filename)
_N_0_0_PHONE

print(len(contours))
11

print(img.shape)
(61, 313)

Comment: @J.D.Even No Contours Files Being Generated Or Written....

Comment: All images you want to process need to be in the same `basepath` folder. Add `print(files)` below `files = listdir(basepath)`. It should print the name of all objects in the folder.

Comment: @J.D. all the images are in same basepath then also same problem exists         print(files)
['1 (103)_A_0_0_NAME.jpg', '1 (103)_N_0_0_CARD.jpg', 'arguments.py', '_N_0_0_PHONE.jpg']

Comment: Take the part of the code that processes the image and see if it works when you hard code the image path

Comment: @J.D.still the problem not resolved.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your code currently does is it draws a line of the contours on the image and then saves it. It does this only for the last image in `image_path_list` and since the `imwrite` is hard coded, it will always result in 1 image only.

This is the process you should follow for each image:
- create a new folder
- find the contours in the image
- for each contour take the boundingRect, the box that contains the contour
- use the dimensions of the boundingrect to create a subimage
- save the subimage with a variable name.

The code below shows this proces for 1 image, you can implement this in `for imagePath in image_path_list:`

Result:
[image]

Code:

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np 
    import os
    from os import listdir

    # get the filenames in directory
    basepath = "C:/Users/Desktop/Images/"
    files = listdir(basepath)
    # declare valid filtypes
    valid_image_extensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".tif", ".tiff"] 

    for name in files:
            # check if it is a valid filetype
            filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(name)
            if file_extension in valid_image_extensions:
                    # create a folder for this image
                    path = basepath+filename
                    if not os.path.exists(path):
                            os.makedirs(path)
                    # load image in grayscale
                    img = cv2.imread(basepath+name,0)
                    # threshold image
                    ret,mask = cv2.threshold(img,240,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
                    # find contours
                    ret, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

                    for i in range(len(contours)):
                            # get contour
                            cnt = contours[i]
                            # get the dimensions of the boundingRect
                            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
                            # create a subimage based on boundingRect
                            sub_img = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
                            # save image of contour with indexed name
                            cv2.imwrite(path+"\contour_"+str(i)+".jpg", sub_img)
```

Comment: I am having trouble while executing this on all 3 images in image path list is it possible for you to write code for same i will be highly thankful to you

Comment: You were inputting the list of filenames, not the individual filenames. I've extended the code such that it processes multiple images from a given folder. Note that there is no check of file type at all. If you run this code twice it will break because of the newly created folders. I'll leave that implementation to you.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-48-c70ee3ac2377>", line 3, in <module>
    path = basepath+filename[:filename.index(".")]

ValueError: substring not found

Comment: Yes, this is what I warned you about. Have you tried to solve it? It wasn't that hard ;)  I've updated the code. You should be good now.

Comment: Only one file is being read.                                                                    print(filename) _N_0_0_PHONE                                                         print(len(contours)) 11                                                                                    print(img.shape) (61, 313)